# Callback ressource using Youtube-Api

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube Api to upload videos on my Youtube channel (using Java).
The callback is fixed to : http://localhost:8080/Callback

How may I change the Callback to a ressource that I design ? For example to http://localhost:8080/services/MyResponse

Comment: I think this might help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595174/google-oauth-the-redirect-uri-in-the-request-did-not-match-a-registered-redirec

Comment: Hmmm!! No, this configuration authorize some URI to be as Callbacks ... BUT it do not do the redirection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection URI is configured in the request sended to accounts.google it self :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=http://google.ca&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
response_type=token
```

... the request that we send contains the redirect_uri and google will redirect the request to this specified redirect_url ...

thanks

Comment: Could you specify where this is configured? I am using samples and can't find this anywhere.