# Getting redirect_uri_mismatch with Sign on With Google

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, google-oauth

I'm getting redirect_uri_mismatch when the backend is attempting to exchange an authorization code for an ID token with Google.

```
400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

***NOTE: The JavaScript front end gets the authorization code just fine.***

I've spent multiple days searching the web, Google's documentation, searching StackOverflow, chatting with ChatGPT. I'm stumped.

React front end using "@react-oauth/google": "^0.12.1"

```
const login = useGoogleLogin({
    flow: 'auth-code',
    onSuccess: async (response) => {
        try {
            var data = { code: response.code };
            const session = await post('api/v1/sessions', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
    onError: error => console.log(error),
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5173/login'
});
return (
    <div className="p-4">
        <div className="space-y-6 text-left">
            <Button label="Sign with Google" onClick={() => login()} type="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Backend is Spring Boot 3.2.2 with Java 21, google-api-client-servlet 2.4.0

```
public GoogleIdToken getIdToken(ClientSecrets secrets, String authorizationCode) {
    try {
        var response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            new NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            secrets.getDetails().getTokenUri(),
            secrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
            secrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
            authorizationCode,
            "http://localhost:5173/login") // redirectUri
        .execute();
        return response.parseIdToken();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

redirectUri: http://localhost:5173/login
Google Console:
[image: GCP Console]

Comment: Try `http://localhost` on the front-end in your React code. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595174/google-oauth-the-redirect-uri-in-the-request-did-not-match-a-registered-redirec

Comment: can i see the full error you are getting the pop up that says redirect url miss match what url does it say?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo The front end is fine. It successfully get an authorization code. I get the following response in a Java exception in the backend when trying to exchange the authorization code for an ID token (JWT):

```
400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```
I added emphasis in my question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: The redirect uri must exactly match the one you're application is sending from probably in the front end.   You should be seeing this error in the browser window

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo So my front end is http://localhost:5173 and my backend is http://localhost:8080. The documentation made the redirectUri value seem more like another password. The front end can successfully get the authorization code sending http://localhost:8080/redirect as the redirectUri parameter. But still getting same error in backend using that same redirectUri value. I wonder what the value of redirectUri will work for both the front end and back end to exchange an auth code for an ID token.

Comment: The redirect uri is the location you want the authorization returned to.  If you are using the client libraries it detects host and port for you.  I would try adding 8080

Comment: Thanks to @wannadream and Linda Lawton - DaImTo for your comments. I found the solution that worked in my specific situation and answered it below. I hope this helps someone in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to follow the documentation for obtaining an authorization code and exchanging it for an ID token (JWT) in the backend: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

Discovered an undocumented value for redirectUri. The value for redirectUri in the backend must be `postmessage`. Found it here: https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/issues/12

When publishing an API always document magical values.